# VS isolated shell creating custom document windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to create custom document windows in VS isolated shell. What I hope to have is something similar to a ToolWindowPane where I can extend it for my custom tool windows and set the content to my custom user control. However, I am not sure if this is possible for VS document windows. I could not find any examples on how to extend the superclass WindowPane in order to create custom document windows that can be repeatedly created dynamically.

Any pointers or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Edit: Or is there a way to prevent tool windows from restoring to its previous state on VS start? I basically want all of the tool windows to act like document windows and reset/delete themselves on close.

Edit2: Solved previous edit. Set transient flag to true, which prevents tool window from opening on IDE start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found work around here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/vsx/thread/d60f8cef-2523-4b53-8f24-92eb90912e7c/

However, if anyone has solution on how to create a custom document pane, that'd be great. ToolWindowPane has several drawbacks that I would rather avoid.